# Dashboard or icons set as home screen in iphone

Tags: iphone, icons, dashboard

hey guys,
I was looking around how I could make dashboard or icons set in iphone, i was looking a lot on the internet but i didn't find the answer. I meant dashboard as home screen in iphone

Thanks

Comment: iPhone has no Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to look at the Three20 library, developed to support the development of the Facebook iOS app. This library will give you the possibility of creating a dashboard like the one in the home screen of the Facebook app.

You can find the source code and documentation at the [official GitHub repository](https://github.com/facebook/three20), lots of info at the [project home page](http://three20.info/), and an example of the Launcher component (probably this is what you need) at [this page](http://three20.info/showcase/launcher).